# Clear RAM inside of a loop R

Tags: r, garbage-collection, ram

Is there a way that I can free up RAM in R inside of a loop on Windows 10? 
Things that does not work:

- `rm()` some variables then try to clean up with `gc(reset=T)`
- `.rs.restartR()` breaks the loop.

Is there any other way to clean up RAM? I m not using variables that are stuck in it.

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be easier (and better!) to optimise your code, or (if you are working with large datasets) to use data.table-solutions... Further advise (imho) is impossible without actual code.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It is huge parallilzed ML ensembel, and when I decide that I do not want to use some bottom layer model I want clear it from RAM. @Wimpel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart R session without interrupting the for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305203/restart-r-session-without-interrupting-the-for-loop)